# Lebesgue integral for unbounded domain.

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose that $\Omega$ is unbounded domain. So i want to know the Lebesgue integral on $\Omega$. Detail:
$$\int\limits_\Omega d\mu=?$$
I think the result is $|\Omega|$. Is it true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost. It is $\mu(\Omega)$. The integral of the simple function $\chi_\Omega$ is *by definition* $\mu(\Omega)$.

Comment: Using the word ``almost'' is tricky in measure theory :)